# Atiyah and Macdonald's proof of the existence of the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, proof-explanation

I have a question regarding the proof of the proposition 2.12 in Atiyah and Macdonald's book.
They say:
" Let C denote the free A-module $A^{(M \times N)}$. The elements of C are formal linear combinations of elements of $M \times N$ with coefficients in A, i.e they are expressions of the form $ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot (x_i,y_i) (a_i \in A, x_i \in M, y_i \in N).$
Let D be the submodule of C genearated by all elements of C of the following types:
$(x+x',y)-(x,y) -(x',y) \\
(x,y+y')-(x,y) -(x,y') \\
(ax,y)- a \cdot(x,y) \\
(x,ay)- a \cdot(x,y) \\$

Let $T= C/D.$ For each basis element $(x,y)$ of $C$, let $ x \otimes y$ denote its image in $T$. Then $T$ is generated by the elements of the form $x \otimes y$ "

And now comes the part I don't understand:

"and from our definitions we have
$(x+x') \otimes y = x \otimes y + x' \otimes y, x \otimes (y + y') = x \otimes y + x \otimes y', (ax) \otimes y = x\otimes (ay) = a(x\otimes y)$"

Where does this come from? What do they mean by "from our definitions"???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the element $x\otimes y$ is the class of $(x,y)\in C$ in the quotient $C/D$. Since by construction $(x+x',y)-(x,y) -(x',y)$ is in $D$, the class of this element is zero in the quotient.

But the class of this element *is* by definition $(x+x') \otimes y - x \otimes y - x' \otimes y$. So $(x+x') \otimes y - x \otimes y - x' \otimes y = 0$, which means $(x+x') \otimes y = x \otimes y + x' \otimes y$.

The same thing happens for the other relations.

Answer (score 1):

For example, $(ax) \otimes y = (ax, y) + D = a (x,y) +D = a[(x,y)+ D] = a(x \otimes y)$, because $(ax,y) - a(x,y) \in D$.